# QGIS: Is there any interactive tool to select previous or next points using fid/attribute table order?

Tags: qgis, filter, point

I have a huge point file (4933873 points, currently in GeoPackage)) looking this way:

[image: point layer in QGIS]

imported from a CSV of following structure:

```
Captured Time,Latitude,Longitude,Value,Unit,Location Name,Device ID,MD5Sum,Height,Surface,Radiation,Uploaded Time,Loader ID
2016-11-04 01:00:07,37.4932,139.93305,38,cpm,,101,e40768be06169b47c412cdbc8b50ee51,,,,2016-11-04 01:00:07.805856,
2016-11-04 01:00:03,37.366713,140.53097,27,celcius,,100079,0654275d9d656aac8f1ee06eaf2ca8d0,462,,,2016-11-04 01:00:03.691745,
2016-11-04 01:00:02,37.366713,140.53097,11,cpm,,100072,b48a5a4b821d04d2071d233d99fc9bf5,462,,,2016-11-04 01:00:03.149019,
2016-11-04 01:00:01,37.366713,140.53097,56,cpm,,100071,654c26d9ad16aa776613db4913a6ee95,462,,,2016-11-04 01:00:01.932265,
```

And I need to remove those orange / red straight lines (airborne data) and keep the rest (ground measured data - car/walk etc.). Unfortunately there is no altitude so I cannot easily filter it out.

Is there any better way to select consecutive points (after selecting one to begin) without need to load attribute table for a whole layer?

Comment: The [Feature Iterator plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FeatureIterator/) may help. It's not updated for QGIS 3.x, but it should work in 2.18.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried converting the points to lines and then deleting the long-distance lines? You can do this with the **Points to Path** tool and then **Select by Attributes** using the `$length` attribute.

If you have also long-distance car tracks and are ok with the assumption that planes travel in a straight line while cars don't, you may add an additional clause to your **Select by Attributes** using the `num_points` function.

Your selection query would be something like:

```
$length > 1000 AND num_points($geometry) <= 2
```

This would select only Polylines longer than 1000 units and containing at most 2 vertices (a straight line).

Comment: Hi, but there are also many long carborne tracks which I need to keep - probably longer than the arborne ones. It would be a curve - not a straight line like from the airplane but of the same or even bigger length.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your issue is that opening the attribute table of such a large file can be very slow with so many features. There are two options to remove the red and orange points without opening the attribute table:

**Create a new layer with only the blue points**

> Processing toolbox > Vector Selection > Select by Attribute

According to the layers panel, the orange and red points have values between 507-3034. I'll assume that this is an exact match of the points you want to remove.

Use the `select by attributes` tool to create a new selection where values < 507.

Right click on the layer name in the layer panel.

- In QGIS 2.18 and older, choose "save as..." then save it in your
  desired format. Be sure to check the box next to "save only selected
  features"
- In QGIS 3.0 and newer, choose "export > Save selected features
  as...".

---

**Filter the existing layer instead of creating a new layer**

> Layer properties > Source > Provider Feature Filter > Query Builder

Substitute the name of your attribute into this expression:

> "attributename" < 507